# Rspec don't show me the its

Tags: ruby, git, rspec

I have this repository on bitbucket

```
bitbucket.org/alu0100786330/prct08
```

And when I clone it in my cloud 9, the Rspec don't show me the its

I have this workspace that containt the repository and here it works right:

```
ide.c9.io/alu0100786330/lpp_67
```

Expected output:

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhsmU.png]]

**BUT** in the second workspace dont show me the results.

The commands that I made:

```
git clone bitbucket.org/alu0100786330/prct08
bundle install
```

And when I execute the rspec with the rake show me this, without its:

[[image: without its]]

What can I do to show the its?

Comment: Is there a `.rspec` file in your project? What are the contents? Is it maybe in the first workspace, but not in the second one (because it is not a file managed by the repo - in the .gitignore for example). By the way both commands are running all examples and passing, it is just the display of results that is different.

Comment: yes was this! thanks

Comment: Have you tried asking? "Show us your its! Show us your its!"

Comment: xDDDDDDDDDDD maybe next time

Comment: So your `.rspec` contained some specific formatter configuration? What do you mean with "its" ?

Comment: The problem was, as said Neil that when I do the clone, the .rspec was in the first workspace, but not in the second. I copy the .rspec in the new workspace and the terminal show me the its perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSpec reads from the `.rspec` configuration file in the directory you run it from. It sounds like in one workspace, that contains `--format documentation`, and in the other, it contains `--format progress` (or nothing, `progress` is default). You just need to add a `.rspec` file to your second workspace, or run `rspec` with the options you want (See `rspec --help`).

If you or your team has an `.rspec` you like, check it into the repository. Individuals can still create a `.rspec-local` that doesn't go in the repository if they want to override some settings just for themselves.